Application properties adding double quotes around array application properties
I have an entry in application.properties
x.y = A BC, A BC DEF
This is then initialized using
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "x")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyProperties {
    @NotBlank
    private final String[] y;
}


On calling a request the first time (on server restart), the properties when I log x.getY() as string I get (A BC, A BC DEF), subsequent requests on the other hand get ("A BC", "A BC DEF") with extra double quotes wrapping the entries of the array.
So far I have tried escaping with \u0020, escaping the whitespace \ , "A BC", "A BC DEF", [A BC, A BC DEF]
How can I ensure I do NOT get the values wrapped in double quotes, i.e - I get (A BC, A BC DEF)?
Spring Boot version - 3.2.3
Java/javac version - 17.0.10

I find the first entry strange and not the second one. How are you logging this?

@M.Deinum I'm using sout as well as using the property in an api call later and both log the same discrepancy.

As stated I find the first strange and not the second.  Logging it will print the array representation and also depending on how you are using this in your API call this might be the case as well (you shouldn'tb e relying on a toString implementation for correctness here).
